# buttonlistening - how to make it professional?

Tags: events, button, user-interface, listener

I want to implement a GUI element that works like a button that reacts different on right/left clicks and dragging.
Say this button is an object. Who is in charge to call the right method on mouseevents from the button and how is it designed in usual programming languages like e.g. AWT in Java?

Answer (score 0):

I don't claim that this is 'the professional way' but this is how I do it.
With lazy initialization and anonymous classes.

```
private JButton btnSpecialbutton;
private JButton getBtnSpecialbutton() {
        if (btnSpecialbutton == null) {
            btnSpecialbutton = new JButton("SpecialButton");
            btnSpecialbutton.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
                    System.out.println("Dragged");
                }
            });
            btnSpecialbutton.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                    if(e.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON1)
                    {
                        System.out.println("Left Mouse Button");
                    }
                    else if(e.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON3)
                    {
                        System.out.println("Right Mouse Button");
                    }
                }
            });
        }
        return btnSpecialbutton;
    }
```